# Can I Use an IF-THEN function in a PowerBi Python Visual to tell if a Chiclet Slicer button is Selected?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a python visual which will export data that's on the screen to a CSV, but currently it runs every time you click on something in the PowerBi project. I have a Chiclet Slicer with two buttons on it, "reviewing" and "reviewed". I would like the python visual to only run the export when the chiclet slicer button is selected to "reviewed"[snip of the Powerbi Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHsGo.jpg)

I have the following. I think I need to make an IF-THEN statement that checks if the "reviewed" button is selected in the Chiclet slicer, then does below code. I can't figure out how to check if the button is selected in python code though. Or is there a way to do this entirely in a python visual so I don't have to use the chiclet at all, the button functionality is important though.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

datas=dataset

frame = pd.DataFrame(datas)

datas.to_csv(r'\\homedirpva1a01\USERSNC$\603225\chromdrivernew\powerbitest.csv',index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to check if the button is selected in python code though.

Add the field to your Python visual and it will appear in your DataFrame.